# Walking-related cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>   Across:
>
> 1. Telephone lacking automobile (5)
> 2. Toy company to put level head before self-importance (4)
> 3. Airport wanderer with large heart eliminates 007 (5)
>
> Down:
>
> 1. Vehicle offering luxurious voyage on startup (5)
> 2. Likeable president and top American seller of furniture (4)
> 3. Two-headed board game led by sixth actor (5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1.Telephone lacking automobile (5)

> NOKIA = No Kia

2.Toy company to put level head before self-importance (4)

> LEGO = L(evel) + Ego

3.Airport wanderer with large heart eliminates 007 (5)

> VAGAR (airport in Faroe Islands) = VagaRbond (wanderer with laRge heart) - bond (007)

1.Vehicle offering luxurious voyage on startup (5)

> VOLVO = Initial letters of clue (&lit)

2.Likeable president and top American seller of furniture (4)

> IKEA = Ike (I like Ike slogan) + A(merican)

3.Two-headed board game led by sixth actor (5)

> VIGGO (Mortensen) = VI (six) + GGO (double headed Go)

With the grid

> [image]

The walking-related title refers to:

> Nordic walking - all the answers have their origins in Nordic countries.
>
>  Nokia - Finland, Lego - Denmark, Vagar - Faroe Islands, Volvo - Sweden, Ikea - Sweden, Viggo Mortensen - Danish/American (and parents met in Norway).

Comment: Well done. I'm sure you see what kind of walking all the clues refer to ...

Comment: Thanks to M Oehm. Your comment sparked extra thought on this!